# How to echo a function response in php

Tags: php

I created a function to check for special characters in a string, but I can't seem to get it to echo the response message

Here is my code

```
<?php
    function chk_string($string){
        if (preg_match('/[\^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>|=_+¬-]/', $string))
        {
            $chk_str="false";
        } else {
            $chk_str="true";
        }
        return $chk_str;
    }
    
$string="this is just a test" ;
chk_string($string) ;
echo $chk_str;
?>
```

The "echo $chk_str" is not echoing anything.

Comment: Use `echo chk_string($string);`. `$chk_str` is only valid _inside_ your function. Also remove the quotes from `"false"` and `"true"`

Comment: I'd recommend you to read the manual about [variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). It's one of the fundamentals you need to know.

Comment: Before diving into preg_match, start with variable scopes.

Comment: Reduce the function to `function chk_string($string) { return preg_match('/[\^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>|=_+¬-]/', $string); }`. No need for any if statement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store returned value in a particular variable if you want to echo that variable  like this,

```
$chk_str = chk_string($string) ;
echo $chk_str;
```

Another way you can just directly echo returned value like this,

```
echo chk_string($string) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you did
`$chk_str = chk_string($string);`
then you could `echo $chk_str;`. 
The `$chk_str` you are trying to echo is only visible in your function.

More description: 
Your function (chk_string) is in a different scope than your echo. 
Your function returns a variable, but that variable is "lost", since you don't assign it to another variable. 
Your code currently does something like this line by line: 
Your function declaration 
$string means "this is just a test" 
your functions result as a string, just floating in the code 
write out a variable that doesn't exist. 

I hope this helped in someway.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about variable scope and it is answered already, but I would recommend you to take a look at variable scope here https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php.
Basically, every variable has its scope and we can not access a variable outside its scope. In your case, scope of variable `$chk_str` is inside function `chk_string` so you can not access it outside of the function. Because you return value of `$chk_str` in function `chk_string` so you still can access its value through response of function `chk_string`, for example:

```
echo chk_string('a string');
```

OR

```
$result = chk_string('a string'); 
echo $result;
```